# differential equation $u''(x)+u(x) =|\cos(x)| $

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am stuck solving the diff-eq. $u''(x)+u(x) =|\cos(x)| $.

How do I find the general solution to this?

The homogeneous part is no problem, but how do I deal with the absolute value of the cosine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can re-write it in the following form:
$$u''(x)+u(x)=\left\{ \begin{array}{rc}\cos x& -\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi k\leq x<\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi k\\-\cos x& \frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi k\leq x<\frac{3\pi}{2}+2\pi k  \end{array}\right.$$
And find the solution according to the segement.

Comment: Shouldn't the OP combine the finial answers as one answer?

Comment: It depends on whether it is possible: the resulted function could be not-differentiable on the segment edges.

Answer (score 2):

You need to solve the following equation for particular solutions

$$ u''(x)+u(x) = \cos(x) \,\quad \cos(x)\geq 0 \,,$$

and

$$ u''(x)+u(x) = -\cos(x) \,\quad \cos(x)< 0 \,.  $$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{{\rm u}''\pars{x} + {\rm u}\pars{x} = \verts{\cos\pars{x}}:\ {\large ?}}$

> Let $\ds{\xi\pars{x} \equiv {\rm u}'\pars{x} + \ic{\rm u}\pars{x}}$ such that
>   $\ds{{\rm u}\pars{x} = \Im\xi\pars{x}}$ and
>   $\ds{{\rm u}''\pars{x} + {\rm u}\pars{x}
>      = \xi'\pars{x} - \ic\xi\pars{x} =\verts{\cos\pars{x}}}$

Then,
$$
\expo{-\ic x}\verts{\cos\pars{x}}
=\expo{-\ic x}\xi'\pars{x} - \ic\expo{-\ic x}\xi\pars{x}
=\totald{\bracks{\expo{-\ic x}\xi\pars{x}}}{x}
$$

> $$
> \expo{-\ic x}\xi\pars{x}=\int\expo{-\ic x}\verts{\cos\pars{x}}\,\dd x + A
> \quad\mbox{where}\quad A\ \mbox{is a constant}\quad\mbox{and}\quad A \in {\mathbb C}
> $$

$$
\xi\pars{x}=\expo{\ic x}\int\expo{-\ic x}\verts{\cos\pars{x}}\,\dd x + A\expo{\ic x}
$$

> $$
> {\rm u}\pars{x}=
> \Im\pars{\expo{\ic x}\int\expo{-\ic x}\verts{\cos\pars{x}}\,\dd x + A\expo{\ic x}}
> $$
>   The constant $\ds{A}$ is determined by the boundary conditions.