# initial value problem: y'' + 4y = f(t) , y(0)= y'(0)=0. f(t) = { 0 if t <3; t if t >3}

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the initial value problem:

$$y'' + 4y = f(t) , y(0)= y'(0)=0. $$
where
$$ f(t) = \begin{cases} 0 &t < 3 \\ t & t > 3\end{cases} $$

I've solved for the homogeneous equation, $y'' + 4y = 0,$ to get the general solution, 
$y = A\cos(2t) + B \sin(2t)$ for some arbitrary constants $A$ and $B$.

But, now where do I go next?

Thanks!

Comment: Even, walk me through it, without giving a solution? I'm just stuck.. don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Find two solutions for for $y'' + 4y = 0$ (Set $y(t) = e^{st}$ and solve for $s$, note that $s$ may be complex. If you don't want to use complex numbers, set $y(t)=e^{\sigma t}\sin(\omega t + \phi)$ instead).
2. Combine those solutions to find a solution of the IVP $y_1'' + 4y_1 = 0$ with boundary conditions $y_1'(0) = 0$ and $y_1(0)=0$.
3. Then find a solution for $y'' + 4y = t$. (Set $y(t) = At$ and solve for $A$)
4. Combine the two solutions from (1) and the one from (3) to find a solution fo the IVP $y_2'' + 4y_2 = t$ with initial conditions $y_2'(3) = y_1'(3)$ and $y_2(3) = y_1(3)$ for $t \geq 3$.
5. Now $$
       y(t) = \begin{cases}
         y_1(t) &\text{if $t \leq 3$} \\
         y_2(t) &\text{if $t > 3$}
       \end{cases}
     $$ is the solution you're looking for

Here's a plot of the solution as calculated by Mathematica
[image: Solution]

Comment: So I got as my general solution to part 1: 
y = A*cos(2t) + B*sin(2t)

Comment: However, when I solve this for y(0)=y'(0)=0, I get A = B = 0. 
That doesn't make any sense to me...

Comment: It's certainly possible that solution of the first part  is $y_1(t)=0$...

Comment: any pointers @fgp ?

Comment: I already gave you one... $A=B=0$ isn't a problem, it simply means that the solution for $t \in [0,3]$ is identically zero...

Comment: Just continue with step 3

Comment: thanks it all made sense finally :)

Answer (score 1):

A [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/226741/differential-equation-uxux-cosx/226747#226747). In fact, you need to solve these two differential equations

$$ \begin{cases} y'' + 4y = 0 &t < 3 \\ y'' + 4y = t & t > 3\end{cases} .$$

Answer (score 1):

Again, as referenced above, I would Laplace transform.  The LT of the RHS is not hard:

$$\int_0^{\infty} dt \, f(t) e^{-s t} = \int_3^{\infty} dt \, t\, e^{-s t} = \frac{(3 s+1) e^{-3 s}}{s^2}$$

The equation for the LT $Y(s)$ is then

$$Y(s) = \frac{(3 s+1) e^{-3 s}}{s^2 (s^2+4)}$$

The ILT $y(t)$ may be found by using the theory of residues on

$$y(t) = \frac{1}{i 2 \pi} \int_{c-i \infty}^{c+ i\infty} ds \frac{(3 s+1)}{s^2 (s^2+4)} e^{s (t-3)}$$

That is, for $t>3$, we close the loop to the left and sum the residues of the poles at $s=0$ and $s=\pm2 i$.  For $t<3$, we close the loop to the right and enclose no poles, so the ILT is zero there.

I will leave the details of evaluating the residues to the reader; I get

$$f(t) = \left [ \frac{t}{4} - \frac{3}{4} \cos{[2 (t-3)]} - \frac18 \sin{[2(t-3)]}\right] \theta(t-3)$$

where $\theta$ is the Heaviside step function.

Comment: Hi, we haven't learnt about summing the residues of the poles.. What does it mean to close the loop?

Comment: The inverse Laplace transform is integrated along a line in the complex plane, $\Re{s}=c$.  "Closing the loop" means connecting the line with a large semicircle centered at the origin.  The residue theorem states that the integral about a closed loop in the complex plane is equal to $i 2 \pi$ times the sum of the residues of the poles inside the closed loop.  This will make sense if you've had complex variables/analysis.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, have not done complex variables/analysis.

Answer (score -1):

I would use a Laplace transform:

$$\scr{L}(y''+4y)=\scr{L}f(t)$$

$$s^2Y(s)+4Y(s)=F(s)$$

$$Y(s)=\frac{F(s)}{s^2+4}$$

$$y(t)=\scr{L}^{-1} \frac{f(s)}{s^2+4}$$

The Laplace transform of $f(t)$ is $\frac{1}{s^2}e^{-3s}$.

$$y(t)=\scr{L}^{-1}\frac{1}{s^2(s^2+4)}e^{-3s}$$

Using partial fraction decomposition:

$$\frac{1}{s^2(s^2+4)}=\frac{1}{4}(\frac{1}{s^2}-\frac{1}{s^2+4})$$

$$\frac{1}{4}\scr{L}^{-1}\{\frac{1}{s^2}-\frac{1}{s^2+4}\}=\frac{1}{4}t-\frac{1}{8}\sin{2t}\space u(t)$$

$$\scr{L}^{-1}e^{-3s}=\delta{(t-3)}$$

The property of convolution states that:

$$f(t) * g(t)=\scr{L}\{f(s)g(s)\}$$

$$y(t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\delta{(\tau-3)}(\frac{1}{4}t-\frac{1}{4}\tau-\sin{(2(t-\tau))})u(t-\tau)d\tau$$
$$y(t)=(\frac{1}{4}t-\frac{3}{4}-\frac{1}{8}\sin(2t-6))u(t-3)$$

Comment: Oh.. well.. we only care for t > 0.

Comment: Soo.. for t>3, f(t) = t. Hence, $L(f(t)) = 1/(s^2)$ But then I need to time shift it, to deal with $ t \in (0,3)$

Comment: No, that doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: @GinaKousalis check my edit. A quick check will show that the solution satisfies the differential equation.

Comment: How did you get your LT? It differs from  mine, and I am sure mine is OK.

Comment: @RonGordon Mine just seems to be missing the $\cos{2(t-3)}$ term. Where did it come from though? Perhaps I did my partial fractions incorrectly.

Comment: You solution does not satisfy the differential equation.  Check your work.